# How to add abstract class with generic as argument of delegate in c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, delegates, abstract

I have an abstract class called `StatesHandler` with a generic type `T`.
In this class, I have a delegate which is called from whithin the class:

```cs
public abstract class StatesHandler<T>
{
    public event Action<StatesHandler<T>> OnStatesChanged;

    private void Function(){
        OnStatesChanged(this);
    }
}
```

I then have an implementation of this abstract class, where `State` is an enum:

```cs
public class MyStatesHandler : StatesHandler<State>{}
```

In a third class, I add a listener to this delegate:

```cs
public class MyThirdClass
{
    private MyStatesHandler myStatesHandler;

    private void AddListener()
    {
        myStatesHandler.OnStatesChanged += StateChanged;
    }

    private void StateChanged(StatesHandler<State> statesHandler)
    {
    }
}
```

My question is why does the function added to the listener need to be of signature `StatesHandler<State>` and not simply `MyStatesHandler`?

Shouldn't both work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnStatesChanged`takes as a parameter a `StatesHandler<T>` or anything derived from `StatesHandler<T>`.

Suppose therefore we also had

```
public class SomeOtherHandler : StatesHandler<State>{}
```

It would be possible to invoke `OnStatesChanged` passing an object of this class as a parameter, since it is derived from `StatesHandler<T>`. However, this could not be passed to

```
private void StateChanged(MyStatesHandler statesHandler)
{
}
```

since there is no inheritance relationship between `MyStatesHandler` and `SomeOtherHandler`.

Thus the event handler must take a base class parameter.

Comment: Thanks, interesting!
But I would like MyStatesHandler to only accept listeners from this class type and derivates of the class, is this possible?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution. As it stands, `SomeOtherHandler` seems unnecessary, since it has no additional methods. I appreciate that's just for simplification, but maybe if you showed how `SomeOtherHandler` differs from its base class, it would easier to see a way around it.